# SelectNodes in XPathNodeList

Tags: powershell, xpath

Given an XPathNodeList derived with something like this

```
$settingsNodes = $temp.xml.SelectNodes('/Settings/*')
```

And given a particular node Name or ID, I can iterate the XPathNodeList, test for a match and increment a counter. However, I wonder if there is something more elegant, along the lines of

```
$count = $settingsNodes.SelectNodes("//$nodeName")
```

That doesn't work because an XPathNodeList doesn't have a SelectNodes method, and I can't seem to find anything that does work. Googling XPathNodeList SelectNodes returns all sorts of references to SelectNodes as a method of XmlNode, but nothing on XPathNodeList.
My specific condition means I am almost certainly never looping through more than a few hundred to perhaps a thousand nodes, so maybe it really doesn't matter, it just seems like there is probably or more graceful solution and I just haven't found it.

EDIT: For additional context.

In one condition I might have this XML and I just want to catch and log the duplicate UserLogFilePath node.

```
<Settings>
    <JobsXML>[Px~Folder]\Resources\jobs.xml</JobsXML>
    <JobLogFilePath>[Px~Folder]\Logs</JobLogFilePath>
    <JobLogFileName>[Px~StartTime] Job [Px~Job][Px~Error]</JobLogFileName>
    <MachineLogFilePath>[Px~Folder]\Logs</MachineLogFilePath>
    <MachineLogFileName>[Px~Now] [Px~Action] [Px~Set] on [Px~Computer][Px~Error][Px~Validation]</MachineLogFileName>
    <ResetLogFilePath>[Px~Folder]\Logs</ResetLogFilePath>
    <ResetLogFileName>[Px~Now] [Px~Action] on [Px~Computer][Px~Error][Px~Validation]</ResetLogFileName>
    <UserLogFilePath>[Px~Folder]\Logs</UserLogFilePath>
    <UserLogFilePath>C:\Program Files</UserLogFilePath>
    <UserLogFileName>[Px~User] on [Px~Computer]</UserLogFileName>
    <UserContextMember></UserContextMember>
    <UserContextNotMember>Administrators</UserContextNotMember>
</Settings>
```

If there are no duplicates the entire Settings node is imported into my XML variable in memory.
Later, I might have this XML and I want to catch duplicate IDs, both in and outside of any Product_Group.

```
<Definitions>
    <Products>
        <Product_Group id="Miscellaneous">
            <Product id="ADSK360">
                <DefaultShortcut>Autodesk 360.lnk</DefaultShortcut>
                <ProgramDataFolder>C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Autodesk ReCap</ProgramDataFolder>
                <ProgramFolder>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autodesk Sync</ProgramFolder>
                <ShortcutPath>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Autodesk</ShortcutPath>
            </Product>
            <Product id="ADSK360">
                <DefaultShortcut>Autodesk 360.lnk</DefaultShortcut>
                <ProgramDataFolder>C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Autodesk ReCap</ProgramDataFolder>
                <ProgramFolder>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autodesk Sync</ProgramFolder>
                <ShortcutPath>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Autodesk</ShortcutPath>
            </Product>
        </Product_Group>
        <Product id="ADSK360">
            <DefaultShortcut>Autodesk 360.lnk</DefaultShortcut>
            <ProgramDataFolder>C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Autodesk ReCap</ProgramDataFolder>
            <ProgramFolder>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autodesk Sync</ProgramFolder>
            <ShortcutPath>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Autodesk</ShortcutPath>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</Definitions>
```

If there are no duplicates the Product_Groups are eliminated (it's just a convenience for users managing their XML) and all the Products are imported into the Products node in memory.
Subsequent product files are checked first for internal duplicates, and if none are found checked for duplicates already in the main XML, and if none found the file's XML is merged. This repeats for potentially a hundred or more total files in some cases.

The current loop based approach is inelegant, especially for the internal duplicates test. I make an XPathNodesList, say of all the Products, in the candidate XML. This is where SelectNodes is nice because it can find Products in a Product_Group or not. Then I loop through each product and test it against the whole XPathNodesList. Ugly because a list of only 10 nodes means 100 times through the loop. When testing the candidate against the final XML it's more efficient, but still ugly.

EDIT #2:
Taking a stab at using Select, I have this correctly finding duplicate nodes.

```
$settingsNodes = $temp.xml.SelectNodes('/Settings/*')
Write-Host "$($settingsNodes.count)"
Write-Host "$(($settingsNodes | select -unique).count)"
```

But how does one find only duplicate IDs? Better yet duplicate IDs with the same node name? Since a different node name but the same ID would actually not be a duplicate. -unique is a bool I see, so my guess is I am about to learn something more about pipelining, because I need to extract the IDs to pipe to Select -unique, which isn't Where-Object. How does one just pull the IDs in this case?

OK, gut test here. I think maybe I am trying to be a bit too clever when in fact there is a much easier solution. To wit...

```
$settingsNodes = $temp.xml.SelectNodes('/Settings/*')
$unique = $duplicate = @()
foreach ($node in $settingsNodes) {
    if ($unique -contains $node.Name) {
        $duplicate += $node.Name
    } else {
        $unique += $node.Name
    }
}
Write-Host "u: $unique"
Write-Host " "
Write-Host "d: $duplicate"
```

Swap Name for ID and it works for that too. The SelectNodes will take care of eliminating the Product_Group. And similarly I can build an array of the nodes in Final to test against with the now unique list of candidate nodes. 
So, am I missing something that is going to bite me? Or should I just go ahead and kick myself? ;)

Comment: have you considered just using the dot notation that ps provides for xmls instead of xpath? i would consider it more elegant :)

Comment: Paul, there is a lot of other functionality where XPath has been needed, like selecting for specific attribute values and such. And in this example, the first test is for node name, but the next thing I would need to implement is count by attribute. That said, if I can use something other than XPath for this specific need I am all ears. XPath is just what I am most familiar with, and it seems to offer the most capabilities so I figured the solution would likely be found there.

Comment: Why not simply use `$temp.xml.SelectNodes("/Settings//$nodeName")`?

Comment: maybe so - `Evaluate("count(/Settings//$nodeName)")` ?

Comment: Ansgar, there is a further issue where the Nodes being selected could be in a parent node or not, so the first SelectNodes takes care of that. But from that list I want to test for duplicates, and it is doing a SelectNodes on that list that has me stumped. So, the example is a little bit simplistic, but the alternatives that could work for the example fail in the more complex conditions I also have. So again, is there no way to selectNodes on an XPathNodesList? Because if not, then my loop and test approach does in fact work, and is my best bet I suspect.

Comment: If you want to test for duplicates, why not do a `$settingsNodes | select -unique` and compare the node count before and after?

Comment: Ansgar, that would tell me if there are duplicates, but it wouldn't identify the actual duplicates, correct? I am working from customer XML files, so I want to be able to log exactly what duplicates they have so they can more easily revise their XML. In addition, there is a test for duplicates in one file, but I am also compiling multiple files in memory, so at validation of each new file I need to test for internal duplicates and duplicates in the compiled XML to that point. So, I am pointed back at the fact that my need is complex enough I might as well not worry about rolling my own loop.

Comment: If you need to identify the duplicates, use `Group-Object` and select groups that have a count > 1.

Comment: Why not simply  `$temp.xml.settings.<nodeName>` ?

Comment: @Gordon you can select nodes based on ancestor/parent properties as well. If you show us an XML sample it might be easier to point you in the right direction

Comment: Mathias, OP has been revised to show some (somewhat) representative XML. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, select -unique offers an interesting approach, thanks Ansgar!. I will need two functions I suspect, one for internal duplication and one for external, but that helps massively. Even when doing the external test, the loop is only for the number of nodes in the candidate XML, because I can use SelectNodes on the main XML, knowing that what is there is guaranteed unique. For internal testing I can only loop if I know there are duplicates, and I can remove the unique one from the list to arrive at the duplicates for the log. I just hope I can define "unique" as Same Name, or Same ID.

Comment: Because I could have a situation where a node uses the same Name or ID, but is internally not unique. Name seems to be covered (the settings duplicate is same name, different content, and Unique works). But how do I Select on ID? See OP for the new code I am trying.